# How big of a temperature difference is needed to power a thermoelectric generator?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, estimation, thermoelectricity

I'm really curious about this and haven't been able to find a formula to calculate the types of voltages I could generate based on differences in temperature. An example of interest is [The PowerPot](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/david-toledo/the-powerpot) which can charge a phone by boiling water over a campfire (snow would work better due to a larger difference).

I know that the average temperature of a campfire (well stocked) is roughly $1000^\circ C$ and through several Google searches I have ***very roughly*** estimated the average surface temperature of the planet at $15^\circ C$ and am going with my original educated guess that the temperature of the water used is roughly $20^\circ C$. This is a massive difference in temperature and I wonder if it's mandatory.

With some further research into the topic, I have found a formula which hasn't been 100% helpful.

### Seebeck Coefficient

You can read more on this one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_coefficient); however, to sum it up:

$$S = -\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta T}$$

Where $\Delta V$ is the voltage difference between the hot and cold sides, and $\Delta T$ is the temperature difference. The negative sign is from the negative charge of the electron and the conventions of current flow.

---

Is the difference in temperature always required to be this drastic? How do I calculate the correct difference in temperature needed to achieve a specific voltage output? How do I calculate $\Delta V$ when both sides are ambient temperatures instead of physical (can touch it) objects?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page of [Seeback effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect), $S$ seems to be a linear coefficient, therefore you would get proportionally lower $\Delta V$ with lower $\Delta T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thermoelectric device the generates electricity in the difference between your skin temperature and the surrounding air temp.